Correlation alternatives / How to go about testing this relationship?
I have a large set of temperature data from upstream and downstream gauges. I am trying to find the influence of dam release on downstream temperatures. To do this, I am comparing correlation between the tailwater gauge (placed right below the dam) against various downstream sites. Here is my dataset.
> dput(head(TravelTimeAdjustedSaltData))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1709942400, 1709943300, 1709944200, 
1709945100, 1709946000, 1709946900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), S1 = c(12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 
12.824443359375, 12.824443359375, 12.78154296875), S2 = c(12.86734375, 
12.86734375, 12.86734375, 12.910244140625, 12.86734375, 12.824443359375
), S3 = c(12.223837890625, 12.223837890625, 12.26673828125, 12.26673828125, 
12.223837890625, 12.26673828125), S4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.8908984375, 
7.847998046875), S5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), S6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), S7 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), S8 = c(12.309638671875, 12.309638671875, 
12.26673828125, 12.3525390625, 12.3525390625, 12.309638671875
), S9 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), S10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), S11 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), GaugeTemp = c(8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2, 8.2), GaugeHeight = c(70.83, 
70.84, 70.84, 70.85, 70.83, 70.83)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

The data is adjusted for the waters travel time downstream and that is why there are NAs on the first few rows in some columns. Anyways, I ran Spearman correlations, but found a pattern that was not expected and therefore, think that the correlation is not indeed testing what I am actually wanting to find out. What I found is that sites further downstream (S10 / S11) actually had higher or around the same correlation with the Tailwater Gauge as the first site downstream (S4). I have included both the S4 (closest site downstream from tailwater) and S11 (furthest from tailwater) to show what I am saying.  This should not be the case as the influence of the dam releases on downstream temperature should decrease over distance. This leads me to believe that the correlation test is not the answer to my question.


cor.test(TravelTimeAdjustedSaltData$GaugeTemp, TravelTimeAdjustedSaltData$S11, method = "spearman", na.rm=TRUE)
cor.test(TravelTimeAdjustedSaltData$GaugeTemp, TravelTimeAdjustedSaltData$S4, method = "spearman", na.rm=TRUE)
I do not know how to go about testing the cause of dam release (aka the tailwater gauge temperature readings) with the effect (downstream temperature readings). I am looking into some sort of non-parametric regression between the two but not sure if that is the correct way to go about it. Any help would be very much appreciated. I am just wanting a statistical way to show that the dam release is indeed having an effect downstream or not. The correlation is not seeming to serve that purpose (not exactly sure why though).

Seems more a time series question that a simple association question.

Is there such a thing as cross-correlation with repeated measurements?

It's not meaningful to do a null hypothesis significance test here, since you know a priori that the upstream and downstream temperatures must be correlated, since there are at least two physical mechanisms for it (the upstream flows into the downstream, and both are affected by the ambient temperature). So for a sufficiently large sample, you must find the result is "significant"; this isn't useful. More useful would be quantify the degree to which the two are correlated -- this is a so-called "effect size" analysis. How to quantify correlation depends on what you can do with the result.

Try looking at the data as scatterplots, with the horizontal axis being the dam tailwater temperature and the vertical axis being a downstream gauge temperature. I am guessing that you will find that the nearer gauge (S4 I guess) is very closely tied to the tailwater gauge, and the farther gauge (S11) is more loosely tied. You could quantify that by plopping a Gaussian bump on each scatterplot -- the covariance describes how tight or loose is the cloud of points.

Ok. This makes sense to me. I am confused by what you mean for plotting a Gaussian bump on each scatterplot. From what I am understanding, that would be plotting a normal distribution over the scatterplot I am creating. I am probably misunderstanding, as I am very new to stats and r in general, but how would this quanitfy the effect-size. And also how would you go about plotting the gaussian bump? Thanks.
